# EF4 Code First pre-generated view has different hash values in other machines

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, t4

My pre-generated views for EF4 Code First using this [T4 template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ae7730ce-ddab-470f-8456-1b313cd2c44d) does not work in the build server. I am not re-generating the view in the build server, just compile and run the MSTest. Error is thrown when the tests are ran:

> System.Data.MappingException: The mapping and metadata information for
>   EntityContainer 'DB' no longer matches the information used to create
>   the pre-generated views

I ran the same template in another machine and the hash values are different. I guess this is the reason why its it does not work in the build server. The hash values are different at runtime in other machines, hence the verification fails and throws the exception.

Im using:

- VS 2010 Pro
- .Net Framework v4.0.30319
- Entity Framework v4.2 (Code First)
- [EF CodeFirst View Generation T4 Template for C#](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ae7730ce-ddab-470f-8456-1b313cd2c44d) (v1.0.1) - slightly modified GetEdmxSchemaVersion to return the correct EntityFrameworkVersions version for my setup.
- using Class Library project template

The tests that I am running connects to a SQL DB file that is checked in with the code.

I have checked the build server and its using the same EF dll version and .Net Framework version.

Any idea why the hash values are different?

**UPDATE:**
I've generated and compared two XML file from two dev machines using *EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx()*.

Here is schema version (the same in both machine):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Edmx Version="2.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
```

The obvious difference are the order some nodes in the XML files. Here is an example:

Machine 1:

```
<EntityType Name="PersonEntity" BaseType="Self.Entity" />
<EntityType Name="CompanyEntity" BaseType="Self.Entity" />
```

Machine 2:

```
<EntityType Name="CompanyEntity" BaseType="Self.Entity" />
<EntityType Name="PersonEntity" BaseType="Self.Entity" />
```

Any idea why they are in different order?

**UPDATE 2:**
The Edmx (xml) from the build server is also different for the other 2 dev machines. Again, the order of some nodes are different.

Machine 1 and build server both have System.Data.Entity.dll (same File and Product version -- *v4.0.30319.1*) in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089.

**UPDATE 3:**
I also looked at the version of System.Data.Entity.Design.dll. The T4 template references this assembly. Machine 1 has two copies of this dll ... in GAC (v4.0.30319.233) and in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0 (v4.0.30319.1). This is also true in the build server and Machine 2. I wonder if hash validation function during runtime is using this dll as its not referenced in my project. If it does, which version is used. But then again, the hash validation is successful in Machine 1.

Comment: The hash would be different if models are different. Can you do EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx() for both contexts and compare the results. Also, what did you have to modify in the T4 template? 1.0.1 should be the version that reads the version directly from the edmx so I am curious why it did not work for you.

Comment: @Pawel, the models are the same. I sure of this because I ran my tests before commit and all tests passed. I modified the T4 template because I was getting error in this line: "EntityFrameworkVersions.Version3". I am using .Net 4, Version3 was added in .Net4.5. I will try your suggestion re: EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx()

Comment: @Pawel, I simply commented out that line from the T4 template.

Comment: Are you sure .NET Framework 4.5 is not *installed* on any of the machines you use? Even if you are targeting .NET Framework 4 you would be using .NET Framework 4.5 at runtime. You would be getting Version3 if .NET Framework 4.5 was installed on your box. Can you post the output of what EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx returns on both machines (just the first few lines should be enough).

Comment: @Pawel See my update. The two machines I've used are have .Net 4.0 (runtime and framework).

Comment: The order will matter. This is hash and hashing algorithms return different hashes for different strings. Can it be that one of your machines is 64-bit and the other is 32-bit? AFAIK CLR can return properties in different order for different architectures when using reflection. Since the model is built using reflection this would explain the ordering issue. (btw. thanks again for reporting the issue with the Version in the template. I don't have a machine with .NET Framework 4 and could not check this. I will take a look at this.)

Comment: @Pawel, yeah I know. The XML generated should exactly the same to get the same hash. Both dev machines are 64-bit. The build server is also 64-bit.

Comment: I am running out of ideas then... The last stupid question I have - did you install Entity Framework June 2011 CTP by any chance on one of these machines? (See my blog post on this: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/04/11/entity-framework-zombie-a-k-a-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp/)

Comment: @Pawel, negative. I did not install Entity Framework June 2011 CTP. EF was added via nuget and committed with the code.

Comment: Then I don't know what is happening. There must be something different on your machines but I don't know what. Sorry.

Comment: Can you do dir %Windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089 on both machines and show what you get? Also can you check and post the versions of the above assemblies? (from command line do start %Windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089 - it should open windows explorer, rightclick the file and go to Details tab where you can find File and Product versions (should be the same))

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I still don't know why you have different results if you have the same versions of System.Data.Entity.dll everywhere :(

Comment: @Pawel, thanks for the help. Can you look at my 3rd update? Not sure if its relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the update. System.Data.Entity.Design.dll is not used at runtime and for view generation it actually calls into the System.Data.Entity.dll to get the views.

Comment: I got one more idea from one of my colleagues. VS is a 32-bit app so the views will be generated as if on a 32-bit box even if the machine is 64-bit. When you run your app on a 64-bit it will run as 64-bit. The order of types/members/properties etc. returned when using reflection is different between 64-bit and 32-bit processes. Can you force your app to run as 32-bit app (use Corflags {assembly} /32BIT+) and verify the views work? You need to run corflags on the .exe

Comment: @Pawel, thanks for the reply. I will try your suggestion tomorrow. I was running MS Tests on the build server (64-bit, no VS installed there), by the way. However, didnt I already do what you are suggesting when I use the T4 template in VS2010 to pre-generate the views on two 64bit dev machinens but resulted to different hash values?

Comment: If you generated views on a dev box with VS2010 and then run the app on this box then I think it's pretty much the same.

Comment: @Pawel, We're having the same problem as rino.batin.  We have 4 dev machines and each one was getting different hashes.  We generated the XML and found that many of the properties were just in a different order.  We're using EF 5.0.0 on VS2010 SP1.  We compared our DLLs and they're all the same version.  I was able to narrow it down to classes that had partial classes or derived classes.  When there are partial classes or derived classes, it seems to traverse down the partial/derived class in a random order.

Comment: @Pawel, For example, for a partial class, it would enter all the properties that are in file1, then all the properties that are in file2.  In some machines, it would start with file2, then work on file1.  For derived classes, it would randomly pick Derived1 or Derived2 and create the XML for those (where Derived1:Base and Derived2:base).  Any idea how the properties are ordered and what affects the ordering?

Comment: @TTat: This is a very interesting and useful hint. I think that unfortunately reflection does not guarantee the order. While it is mostly stable we noticed that the order is different on x86 than x64. Now as you discovered partial classes make it even worse. We started thinking about resolving this in EF6 but we have not arrived at solution yet.

Comment: Also, I have tried running EdmxWriter to see what the XML looks like.  Surprisingly, I get different results depending on when I call it.  I'm not exactly sure what affects it.  It seemed to get one result earlier in the application and another result if I left the application go a little further.  All this was before it ever accessed my DbContext.

Comment: @Pawel, Wouldn't a simple answer be to just sort the results that come back from Reflection?  I'm looking through the source code, and I found one spot that looks like it would work.

In TypeMapper.cs, MapDerivedTypes method (line 232), it does a foreach through the derived types.

'foreach (var derivedType in _knownTypes.Where(t => t.BaseType == type).ToList())'

Couldn't it be changed to something like

'foreach (var derivedType in _knownTypes.Where(t => t.BaseType == type).OrderBy(a => a.FullName).ToList())'

Couldn't the same thing be done for the properties/associations too?

Comment: @TTat yes and no. The reason why it is not sorted now is that in the vast majority of cases the order of properties returned by reflection matches the order as they are declared on the class. This in turn results in having the same order of columns in the database. And this is the expectation people have. If the properties were force-ordered this would be broken or people would have to configure each property be it by using attributes or in OnModelCreating and the "convention over configuration" principle CodeFirst tries to follow would be dead.

Comment: @Pawel I see.  I noticed that too.  I moved our partial classes into the same file and our XML was closer, but we still had our derived types out of order.  I wonder how Reflection is determining the order when classes are partial classes and derived classes?

Comment: @rino.batin - FYI there were some changes to how pre-generated views are handled in EF6. Firstly we removed one of the hashes, secondly the other hash we generate should not change even if orders of properties or entities change. Here it the link to the work item: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/606

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question. Here's how we solve the main problem (how to pre-generate views in EF Code First that is usable in different machines). I am now using .Net runtime 4.0.30319.17929.

1. In the ABC.csproject where MyContext.cs is located, delete the T4 template and MyContext.Views.cs.
2. Compile ABC.csproject
3. Create a console app that will generate the views. I copied most of Pawel's T4 template. Reference the ABC.dll (and other required dlls). Here's one of the changes:

   var edmx = GetEdmx(typeof(MyContext));
4. Save the string output of GenerateViews() to a text file.
5. Run the console app.
6. Add new file named MyContext.Views.cs to ABC.csproject and copy the content of the text file to this class.
7. Recompile ABC.csproject

I find my solution insane and must be simplified or automated but it works.

Comment: I ended up using this:
https://github.com/IdeaBlade/EdmTasks Sometimes you'll need to build twice for the hash to be correct.